# Bean method not being invoked

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Turns out that faces-config.xml was overriding the inline annotation ViewScoped in my Controller class w/ RequestScoped.  Fixed it and that seem to solve the problem.

---

This question does not have an answer here  [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked) and if you think it does, please provide a working fix/example using primefaces fluidGrid extension.

I am using primefaces ui exension fluidGrid : http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/fluidgrid/dynamic.jsf

I can't seem to invoke profileController.testControl() , if I place the commandButton outside of the fluidGrid it works fine , but not within the grid. Any ideas?

I've tested by changing my bean to @ViewScoped , there are no nested forms etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="resultList" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>

<h:form id="form1" rendered="true">

    <!-- Grid -->
    <pe:fluidGrid value="#{resultList}" var="showvar" hGutter="20" rowKeyVar="rowKey" fitWidth="true" hasImages="true" rendered="true" >        
        <pe:fluidGridItem rendered="true" >
          <p:panel id="seriesPanel"  rendered="#{showvar.isSeries()}"></p:panel>                    
          <p:panel id="episodePanel" rendered="#{!showvar.isSeries()}" >

           <p:commandButton value="click me" action="#{profileController.testControl()}"/>

           <!-- another button attempt that doesn't work -->
           <p:commandButton process="fluidGrid" value="click me again" ajax="false" actionListener="#{profileController.testControlEvent()}" />

          </p:panel>                             
        </pe:fluidGridItem>         
    </pe:fluidGrid>

</h:form>

</composite:implementation>
</html>
```

---

```
//Tried with  @ViewScoped as well
@Model
public class ProfileController {
    public void testControl(){
        log.info("---------------------------------------");
        log.info("TEST CONTROL CLICKED");
        log.info("---------------------------------------");
    }

    public void testControlEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent){
        log.info("---------------------------------------");
        log.info("TEST CONTROL CLICKED");
        log.info("---------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza which one of the listed issues would it be ?

Comment: From your code, I cannot be sure.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I added some more code, is there anything more that you need to see to maybe get an idea of what's happening?

Comment: Have you checked the generated HTML code to see if there aren't nested `<form>`s?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No nested forms.

Comment: Check for one of the other 9 reasons...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza lol I've done.

Comment: But from your code, this doesn't seem to happen. Try to move all this code in a single working page to replicate it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what doesn't seem to happen?

Comment: From your given code, it should work.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ahh ok,  I will move everything into a single page and see if the problem still occurs. Note the issue only arises  when I nest the commandButton within a fluidGridItem. If I place the button outside of the fluidGridItem  it works. This does me no good though.

Comment: If it doesn't work even there, I recommend you to add an entry in primefaces forum and report a bug about it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Moved everything onto a single page and it still does work. I will look into reporting  a bug to primefaces. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried <p:commandButton> still the same symptoms.

Comment: Can you share the xmlns definitions from your xhtml page ?

Comment: @yannicuLar  I added it in my edits above.

Comment: is there a js error? is there a request on click? however there's no component with id="fluidgrid" and your second button targets it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried the simple example of having command button inside fluidGrid and it works here.

**XHTML File**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>


    <h:form id="login">
        <pe:fluidGrid value="#{tBean.images}" var="showvar" hGutter="20"
            rowKeyVar="rowKey" fitWidth="true" hasImages="true" rendered="true">
            <pe:fluidGridItem rendered="true">


                <p:commandButton value="click me" action="#{tBean.doAction}" />

            </pe:fluidGridItem>
        </pe:fluidGrid>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**ManagedBean code**

```
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.primefaces.extensions.model.fluidgrid.FluidGridItem;

@ManagedBean(name = "tBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable{

    private List<FluidGridItem> images;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void initialize() {
        images = new ArrayList<FluidGridItem>();

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                images.add(new FluidGridItem("i" + 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public void doAction() {

        System.out.println("Im doing action");
    }

    public List<FluidGridItem> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}
```

Try above and see if that works for  you. If it works then try to use in your implementation.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it work in my project, I'm assuming in might be due to some issues with components within components. I created a barebones project and the bean method is invoked as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes problem with rendered and button not being invoked. Make sure that your `rendered="#{!showvar.isSeries()}"`
works correct or remove it and try again.

Comment: I've tried removing rendered="#{!showvar.isSeries()}" as well , still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

u must update your form i think in your page add 
in the button update=":form1:fluidGrid" if dosent work make the ajax on true it helped to solve a problem like this i hope it will help you